# Duplicate DB with SMO, tries to overwrite source DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I try to duplicate a Database in SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to use a DB as a Template and then copy it under an other name (everything else should be the same) in a server.

I use this code i found on the Web, but it always says, it can not create the source.mdf because it already exists.

```
    // Connect to Server
    Server server = new Server(txtSourceServer.Text);

    // Get the Database to Transfer
    Database db = server.Databases[txtSource.Text];

    // Setup transfer
    // I want to copy all objects
    // both Data and Schema
    Transfer t = new Transfer(db);
    t.CopyAllObjects = true;
    t.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;
    t.CopySchema = true;
    t.CopyData = true;
    t.DestinationServer = txtDestServer.Text;
    t.DestinationDatabase = txtDest.Text;
    t.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
    t.CreateTargetDatabase = true;

    // Transfer Schema and Data
    t.TransferData();

    // Kill It
    server = null;
```

Is this even the right approach or is there some other way? With Oracle i would have used export and import but with the SQL Server i am just lost :(

Comment: Ok, the error is fixed: `Database db = new Database(serverDest, txtDest.Text); db.Create();` was missing